# Mac editor for C#

Tags: c#

Does anyone know of an editor for MacOS that will allow me to see the syntax coloring and automatically perform the indentations for C#? I am compiling and running in the terminal already so I just need an editor. I am currently using Xcode, but there is no coloring or indentation unless I manually add it.

Comment: VisualStudio 2017 was released for MacOS last year

Comment: I was hoping to not need an entire IDE as I'm already compiling in the terminal, but as there are already several responses suggesting VS I will download it.

Comment: @user906357 then it looks like VSCode is what you want. my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about Visual Studio Code? If that is all you need. VSCode is lightweight (especially compared to the big Visual Studio), is a really great code editor, but lacks all designer functions.

https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Answer (score 0):

This is the full blown Visual Studio IDE for mac.
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/

Answer (score 0):

Another excellent cross-platform tool, which I use occasionally even on Windows, is [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/).

Rider has all the usual excellent IDE features that are familiar across all JetBrains tools (including the best refactoring features out there), and it's a lot faster that Visual Studio + [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). The main downside is that, unlike Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code, it isn't free, although you can download a 30-day trial.